# Training with Adam gets slower each epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, keras

I am training a simple neural network in Keras with Theano backend consisting of 4 dense layers connected to a Merge layer and then to a softmax classifier layer. Using Adam for training, the first few epochs train in about 60s each (in the CPU) but, after that, the training time per epoch starts increasing, taking more than 400s by epoch 70, making it unusable.

Is there anything wrong with my code or is this suppose to happen?

This only happens when using Adam, not with sgd, adadelta, rmsprop or adagrad. I'd use any of the other methods but Adam produces far better results.

The code:

```
modela = Sequential()
modela.add(Dense(700, input_dim=40, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
modelb = Sequential()
modelb.add(Dense(700, input_dim=40, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
modelc = Sequential()
modelc.add(Dense(700, input_dim=40, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
modeld = Sequential()
modeld.add(Dense(700, input_dim=40, init='uniform', activation='relu'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([modela, modelb, modelc, modeld], mode='concat', concat_axis=1))
model.add(Dense(258, init='uniform', activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit([Xa, Xb, Xc, Xd], Ycat, validation_split=.25, nb_epoch=80, batch_size=100, verbose=2)
```

Comment: I could not reproduce this on CPU or GPU. I think you should post this on GitHub as an issue since that is the place to report bugs. Before you do, check that you're not running something else in the background that is interfering.

Comment: I've checked I'm not running anything in the background, updated Theano and Keras and posted this in Github as an issue [link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3576)